# multiple select, add text to default value (option)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla1.7

Can somebody help me please add some text before the default "value" of a multiple select option.

The code that responds for this is:

```
if (!K2HelperPermissions::canAddItem($categories[$i]->value)) {
$categories[$i]->disable = true;
}

$lists['categories'] = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $categories_options, 'catid[]', 'multiple="multiple" style="height:150px"', 'value', 'text',$catid );
```

And here is how the "option" looks now `<option value="891">Uncategorized</option>`

What I want is to add some text before the letters in value="", so for example it looks like:

`<option value="sometext_891">Uncategorized</option>`

Can somebody Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$lists['categories'] = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $categories_options, 'catid[]', 'multiple="multiple" style="height:150px"', 'value', 'text','sometext' . $catid );
```

Comment: The thing is that I also need $catid so each option has different values and I can style separately the options that I want with css..

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm lost. Please clarify the question.

Comment: As I understand `value="891"` - 891 is $catid, so I need to put before $catid some text like `value="sometext891"`..

Comment: I suggested to replace it with the above but you didn't like it... I'll edit to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Before this

`$lists['categories'] = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $categories_options, 'catid[]', 'multiple="multiple" style="height:150px"', 'value', 'text',$catid );` must be cycle or some strings with this:

```
$categories_options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', option-value, option-text);
```

if you will edit "value" in this, the values in the select will change